# Drude model for metals

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

The equation of motion in the Drude model is given by:

$$\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt} = \mathbf{F} - \frac{\mathbf{p}}{\tau},$$

where $\tau$ is the collision time, $\mathbf{F}$ an external force due to magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ and electric field $\mathbf{E}$.

I am confused about what is meant with $\mathbf{p}$. In Simon solid state physics, it is stated that $\mathbf{p}$ is the thermal averaged momentum. But other sources state that it is the average over the momentum of all the electrons. What do people mean when they say: 'Drude model describes the average momentum.'? What is meant with the word **average** in this case?

Comment: How exactly are you defining thermal average?

Comment: I do not know as I asked the question. In Simon solid state, he writes that $\mathbf{p}$ is the 'thermal-average'.

Comment: In Ashcroft and Mermin, they call **p** the total momentum per electron.